# Extracting video fields Respectively

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows

[Extracting individual video fields](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18553/extracting-individual-video-fields) is my previews question.

Based on the Mulvya's answer I can extract the top fields (only) or the bottom fields (only) individual.

Now, I need to extract the video fields In the following order:

TopField1 , BottomField1 ,TopField2 , BottomField2 ,....

Is it possible?

my source format: DV PAL 720x576i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you have to combine the field extraction with interleaving.

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi \
       -filter_complex "[0]field=top[t];[0]field=bottom[b];[t][b]interleave" -r 50 fld%d.png
```

where the `r` value is double the original frame rate (or the same as the field rate).

Comment: would you please tell me how can I get this order : TopField1 , Frame1 ,BottomField1 ,TopField2 , Frame2 , BottomField2 , . . .

Comment: Use interleave as follows: `[t][0][b]interleave=3`

Comment: sorry , I've tested  `[t][0][b]interleave=3`  , but it did not work. it get error.

Comment: You'll have to resize either the field outputs or the full frames, since the latter is double height. You're better off extracting the fields and frames individually and then renaming the files using a script.

Comment: separatefields filter